# Disable Scrollview in Famo.us

Tags: famo.us

How can I disable and re-enable dragging on a scrollview in Famo.us?

[Docs here](https://famo.us/docs/views/Scrollview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine any of these methods would work:

- Unpipe the events from the all Surfaces/Views to the scrollview, this would effectively make it unresponsive to user-input.
- Set 'pointer-events: none' for all the surfaces in the scrollView.
- Create a proxy EventHandler and pipe the events from the surfaces to that EventHandler and then you can pipe/unpipe those events to the ScrollView.

I don't think there is an easier way to do this with the stock ScrollView though..

Alternatively, you could use the FlexScrollView, which contains an option for it:

```
var scrollView = new FlexScrollView({
  enabled: true
});

// disable
scrollView.setOptions({
  enabled: false
});
```

Tutorial: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex/blob/master/tutorials/FlexScrollView.md

Comment: Looks like I'm going to go with famous-flex. Does it automatically unload elements from memory like the stock scrollview?